# Queries on WordPress on Azure

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-front-door, azure-custom-domain

I'm hosting a WordPress Site on Azure VM(Ubuntu 20.04) with Azure DB for MySQL Server as a DB for the website.

I have created 2 environments (Dev & QA) with this setup.

Currently it is accessible on a Static public IP address like this - http://11.22.33.44 on both Dev & QA Environments.

We will be implementing Azure Front Door to add CDN as well as WAF capabilities to the website on a Prod environment.

So my question is:

1. Where to apply the custom Domain name? If I associate my custom domain to the static public ip of the vm then will I be able to associate it to the Front Door as well? (I don't think so).

   If I associate with the Front Door fqdn, then how can I associate with the WordPress site running on Azure VM? Adding it to the wp_options & wp_config will do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm from the Microsoft for Founders Hub team. Typically, when you add a Front Door to your services, you want the initial access to be the Front Door then to your origin front/back end services. That said, it’s common to put the custom domain on the Azure Front Door and have it forward requests to your backend pools (e.g. your Wordpress site (http://11.22.33.44))

Learn more here:

1. Add Custom Domain to Azure Front Door: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain
2. Front Door Origins: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/origin?pivots=front-door-standard-premium
3. Route Traffic: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-routing-architecture?pivots=front-door-standard-premium

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but what I would be doing is:

 - Add a custom domain to Front Door.
 - Have a backend pool configured on VM's Public IP
 - Add domain name in wordpress settings like wp-config, db, etc. 

So when I enter a domain name like http://www.example.com, it will go to the Front Door & subsequently to the WordPress.

I'll also be configuring a NSG rule that allow access to web server only from Front Door as described in the Front Door docs.